# Laravel 5 redirect to home page if attempting to go to login screen

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have a login screen which is the base url (www.mysite.com/).

When a user logs in they are redirected to their home page (/home).

But the can still get back to the login page if they go to the root.

How do I make it so logged in users are sent back to their home page if they are logged in (if they are not, of course they see the login page)?

Answer (score 12):

I did this in my router, although I'm not sure if it's the best solution:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    } else {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use middleware for this.

Laravel 5 has already a 'guest' middleware out of the box you can use, so just doing the following should be enough:

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' =>'guest', function(){
  return view('auth.login');
}]);
```

Then in the middleware file `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated` you can specify where the user is redirected to.

The default is `/home`.

Comment: Doesn't that redirect if they are not logged in? I was looking to redirect them if they are already logged in and try going to the login page.

Comment: No it should redirect them if they are logged in :). The class itself is named RedirectIfAuthenticated its just aliased as guest.

Answer (score 2):

> When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to
>   the /home URI, which you will need to register a route to handle. You
>   can customize the post-authentication redirect location by defining a
>   redirectPath property on the AuthController:

in your AuthController change the redirectPath property

```
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#Authenticating

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't working :( Tried: protected $loginPath = '/';
    protected $redirectPath = '/home';

Comment: cant understand what not working.. can you explain what happen? you are on laravl 5.1?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to delete the cookies in my browser in order to fix the /login redirect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I edited HomeController's construct as given below and worked:

```
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth')->except('index');
  }
```