# Multiauth not working properly using guard for user login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6

I created multi authentication in Laravel for user and admin through same table

> User Migration :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->integer('is_admin')->default(0);
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

> Admin Login controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    //
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
   
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'remember_me'=>'nullable'
    ]);
    $request->merge(['user_type'=>'1']);
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,'is_admin' => $request->user_type
    ], $request->input('remember_me'))) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
    else{
        return back()->withErrors(['message'=>'Username or Password is Invalid'])->withInput($request->all());
    }
    //return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
 

public function logout(Request $request)
    {
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    }
}
```

> Login Controller for User :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    //
    protected $redirectTo = '/user/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
   
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('guest:web')->except('logout');
       // $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
       //$this->middleware('guest:web')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    { 
        return view('pages.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'remember_me'=>'nullable'
        ]);
        $request->merge(['user_type'=>'0']);
        if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,'is_admin' => $request->user_type
        ], $request->input('remember_me'))) {
            return redirect()->intended(route('web.dashboard'));
        }
        else{
            return back()->withErrors(['message'=>'Username or Password is Invalid'])->withInput($request->all());
        }
        //return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
 

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return redirect()->route('user.login-show');
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        $this->data['page_js'] = ''; // ['_admin/plugins/raphael/raphael.min.js','_admin/plugins/morrisjs/morris.js'];
        $this->data['userData'] = Auth::guard('web')->user();
        $this->data['title'] = 'User Dashboard';
        return view('pages.dashboard', $this->data);
    }
}
```

> Route:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login-show');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('login', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin-login-show');
    Route::post('login', 'Admin\LoginController@login')->name('admin.login.post');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin', 'prevent-back-history']], function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'Admin\AdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
    });
    Route::post('logout', 'Admin\LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
    Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('user.login-show');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login.post');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:web', 'prevent-back-history']], function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'LoginController@dashboard')->name('web.dashboard');
    });
    Route::post('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});
```

> Config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],


        // 'users' => [
```

> RedirectIfAuthenticated:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        switch ($guard) {
          
            case 'admin':
              if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
              }

            case 'web':
              if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) { 
                return redirect()->route('web.dashboard');
              }
               
            default:    
              if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) { 
               return redirect('/');
              }
              break;
        }
           return $next($request);
    }
}
```

> Middleware (Authenticate.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Route;
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            if(Route::is('admin.*')){
             return route('admin-login-show');
            }
            return route('user.login-show');
        }

    }
}
```

Here login for both admin and user is working, but in user login i have this route `http://localhost:8000/user/login` for login form if i login then it is redirected to
`http://localhost:8000/user/dashboard` this route but when i access `http://localhost:8000/user/login` login page is still shown but i want it to redirect to `http://localhost:8000/user/dashboard` page, but this functionality is working for admin case.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Could you give your closing paragraph some proofreading? It is not at all clear what your problem is or how it relates to the code above.

Comment: @miken32 login is working for both admin and user issue is if user is already logged in and tries to access login page then login url should redirect to dashboard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424689/laravel-5-redirect-to-home-page-if-attempting-to-go-to-login-screen

Comment: @miken32 i have already defined `protected $redirectTo = '/user/dashboard';` in `LoginController` can you pls check my `RedirectIfAuthenticated` method

Comment: double check you are using the correct `LoginController` there are multiple uses of that controller and you might by mistake be loading the Admin controller which will only redirect if the user is logged in as admin

Comment: @RawSlugs i tried but same issue, after user is logged in it redirect to dashboard but if anyone access login url again that login page is still there

Comment: did you forget the uncomment the middleware? maybe add a `dd()` to the controller so you know 100% the correct one is running. also double check that when a user is logged in, they are logged into the correct guard

Comment: would you be able to share a github repo with your issue?